# Customized standard input

Tags: fortran

i am writing a fortran code,which displays current value of variable.If user wants to retain the current then he simply press enter,else he will enter new string.

my question is,while reading a new string,I want to display >< and cursor should come in between these characters,so that if he enters even space, it would be visible to him

EG:

```
  WRITE(*,*)'Current value is 'curVal
```

in next line statement to  read new character.
As i am new to fortran,I think in read statement we can enter only variales,not formatting.

EG:

```
   READ(*,*)curVal
```

but not Read(*,*)'>',curval,'<'

i want to display like second statemnt.Could you tell me how to deal with read in this case??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a level of terminal IO control not provided / guaranteed by the Fortran language.  You can do something like the following to provide convenient input that can retain the current value by simply hitting the Return/Enter key:

```
write (*, '( "Input new value, or press Enter to retain", I0, ". Input: " )', advance="no") current_value
read (*, '(A)' ) string
if (len_trim(string) == 0 ) then
   new_value = current_value
else
   read (string, *) new_value
end if
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!  one more question how to read string  from keyboard with spaces???